# parametricNDSolve for solving differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

i want to solve this equation and plot it solution w.r.t N2 and theta(0)

`theta''[x] + 2*theta'[x] - 
  Exp[-2*x]*(N2)^2*(theta[x] - 5) + Q1 == 0`
anyone please help

Comment: Look for `DSolve` in the documentation

Comment: And also `ParametricNDSolve` (with capital `P` at the beginning) seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear  what you want plotted nor how you want the plots done. Neither have you specified the range of the variables that are of interest. The following will need to be tailored once you understand your needs.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

{xmin, xmax} = {0, 1};

Manipulate[
 Module[{eqns1, sol1},
  eqns1 = 
  {theta''[x] + 2*theta'[x] - Exp[-2*x]*N21^2*(theta[x] - 5) + Q11 == 0, 
    theta[0] == t01, theta'[0] == tp01};
  sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[eqns1, theta, {x, xmin, xmax}, N21];
  Plot3D[Evaluate[theta[N21][x] /. sol1],
   {x, xmin, xmax}, {N21, 0, 5},
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "N2", "theta"}),
   ClippingStyle -> None]],
 {{Q11, 5, Q1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{t01, 0, "theta[0]"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tp01, 0, "theta'[0]"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
(* spacer *)
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{eqns2, sol2},
  eqns2 = 
  {theta''[x] + 2*theta'[x] - Exp[-2*x]*N22^2*(theta[x] - 5) + Q12 == 0, 
  theta[0] == t02, theta'[0] == tp02};
  sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[eqns2, theta, {x, xmin, xmax}, t02];
  Plot3D[Evaluate[theta[t02][x] /. sol2],
   {x, xmin, xmax}, {t02, 0, 5},
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "theta[0]", "theta"}),
   ClippingStyle -> None]],
 {{Q12, 5, Q1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{N22, 5, N2}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tp02, 0, "theta'[0]"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
(* spacer *)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I want to get a two-dimensional plot with N2 on X-axis and theta(0) on y axis

Comment: @ziauddin - so what are the ranges of interest or values for `Q1` and `x` and the range of interest for `theta[0]`?

Comment: Q1 may be any constant, theta(0) may be from 0-1 and N2 from 0-10

Comment: You still have not specified the range for `x`

Comment: x may be from  0-1